How to set background color of entire page in plain tex?
How can I set background color of entire page in plain TeX? I know how to color text in plain TeX using miniltx package.

in the page head you could do something like \smash{\color{red}\hrule width 10cm height 1cm depth 30cm} positioned to be larger than the page

What do you mean by page head? I did \headline=\smash                      {\color{red}\vrule width 100cm height 100cm depth 30 cm} but it does not fill left margin. For \hrule it complains that You can't use \hrule' here except with leaders.`

as i say you'd need to position it appropriately `\kern-2in before the \smash  for example

Got it. Thanks a lot.

If you can make your comment an answer I can accept it.

answer posted:-)

In the page head (\headline) you could do something like
\kern-3cm\smash{\color{red}\hrule width 10cm height 1cm depth 30cm}

positioned to be larger than the page
